# use css style only on tags which are inside certain tags?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was browsing the css selectors but couldn't really get an idea or just didn't get it.

If I have this HTML:

```
<h1><strong>text</strong></h1>
<h2><strong>text</strong></h2>
<h3><strong>text</strong></h3>
```

is there a way to apply different styles to each strong tag without giving each one a class.

Something like:

```
strong[h1] {}
strong[h2] {}
```

..

or so?

Thanks :)

Comment: Any links to what you were browsing?

Comment: you mean like h1 strong, h2 strong, h3 strong?

Comment: @BoltClock
[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: @jacob
I guess thats it. Let me try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
h1 strong { }
h2 strong { }
h3 strong { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this  and you can also try more than this tag inside tag , drill down as you
wanted example

```
ul li a { font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif }

h1 strong {color:red}
h2 strong {color:green}
h3 strong {color:blue}
```

Comment: What's with the `ul li a` at the beginning?

Comment: even you can use more tag inside tags like ul li a  you can exactly give properties only to <a> which is inside of <ul><li> tags